# ubuntu 13.04 installed with windows 7 but not showing option to select OS to boot with

Tags: system-installation

Hi I am running Windows 7 home basic 64-bit, with amdA8 and radeon graphic card pre installed.
My notebook is HP-Pavilion g6.

I have created the partitions to my 500GB-HDD before installing the ubuntu 13.04, Then i use the ubuntu 13.04 installer disk to install ubuntu. I use the same process as described in the guide which is

1. boot with the installer disk
2. select language, local time etc.
3. Then I select the option to install ubuntu alongside with Windows 7
4. and follow the process.

I got the message for installation complete and restart to begin boot with ubuntu. I do remove the disk from the tray and hit Enter to restart the system.

But when my system started it continued to boot with Windows 7 without showing me the option to select the OS. In my windows disk manager I am able to see two unknown partitions which i think is for swap partition and ext 4 partition.

Comment: Ubuntu has an application called GParted (if it isn't pre-installed, you can easily find it with software centre), which is a partition manager. If you run it, you will be able to see all the partitions on your disc. If would be helpful if you would take a screenshot of how your disc looks like in it, and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the live cd and use `gparted` program to delete those partitions. Then create them again. Choose at least 4GB for `ex4` partition and 3GB for `swap` partition.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you have two hard drives and the master n
Boot record is on the windows drive.  Trying changing your bios setting to point to the one Linux was installed on and grub should load giving you multiple boot options.